# UWP dynamically page

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, uwp

I have a UWP application that will manage 3 entities (Category, Plate, Menu). I have a viewmodel for each entity and a list of viewmodel to choose the entity to manage. So I would like that when I choose a entity in viewmodel's list in the page is load dinamically the usercontrol.

I try to contentcontrol but it is not working.

my xaml code are:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ConfigurationItems}" 
             SelectedItem="{Binding ConfigurationItemSelected, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ConfigurationAbstract}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,0,0">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ConfigurationItemSelected.ConfigurationAbstract}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"/>

        <Grid  Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="1" 
               Visibility="{Binding ImportVisible, Converter={StaticResource b2v} }"
               >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="75*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock  Text="File Importato: "/>
                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path= ConfigurationItemSelected.ImportedFilePathName}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Content="Scegli..." Command="{Binding Path=ConfigurationItemSelected.ChooseCommand}" Margin="5,0"></Button>
                <Button Content="Importa" Command="{Binding Path=ConfigurationItemSelected.ImportCommand}" Margin="5,0"></Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=ConfigurationItemSelected}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Thank you 
Regards

I have update my code with:

```
<Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate  x:DataType="vm:CategoriesViewModel" x:Key="Categorie">
            <controls:UcCategories DataContext="{Binding Path=ConfigurationItemSelected}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate   x:DataType="vm:MenuItemsViewModel" x:Key="Menu">
            <controls:UcMenu  DataContext="{Binding Path=ConfigurationItemSelected}"  />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate   x:DataType="vm:PlatesViewModel" x:Key="Piatti">
            <controls:UcPlates  DataContext="{Binding Path=ConfigurationItemSelected}"  />
        </DataTemplate>

    </Page.Resources>

<ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=ConfigurationItemSelected}">

            </ContentControl>
```

But not working again...

Comment: add a ContentTemplate to your ContentControl and make the ContentControl's Content binding OneWay

Comment: do you have some example?

Comment: You can set the ContentTemplate to a DataTemplate that contains your UserControl like you did in the ListBox's ItemTemplate

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a `DataTemplateSelector` where you can decide which template applied to the ContentControl, depend on some logic, (for now the data's type).

Selector:

```
public class MyDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate CategoryTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate MenuTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate PlateTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is CategoriesViewModel)
        {
            return CategoryTemplate;
        }
        else if (item is MenuItemsViewModel)
        {
            return MenuTemplate;
        }
        else if (item is PlatesViewModel)
        {
            return PlateTemplate;
        }
        else
        {
            return base.SelectTemplateCore(item);
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate  x:DataType="vm:CategoriesViewModel" x:Key="Categorie">
        <controls:UcCategories DataContext="{Binding Path=ConfigurationItemSelected}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate   x:DataType="vm:MenuItemsViewModel" x:Key="Menu">
        <controls:UcMenu  DataContext="{Binding Path=ConfigurationItemSelected}"  />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate   x:DataType="vm:PlatesViewModel" x:Key="Piatti">
        <controls:UcPlates  DataContext="{Binding Path=ConfigurationItemSelected}"  />
    </DataTemplate>

    <local:MyDataTemplateSelector x:Key="TemplateSelector"
                                  CategoryTemplate="{StaticResource Categorie}"
                                  MenuTemplate="{StaticResource Menu}"
                                  PlateTemplate="{StaticResource Piatti}"/>
</Page.Resources>

<ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=ConfigurationItemSelected}" 
                ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TemplateSelector}"/>
```